# RxJS zip and pipe in combination not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, rxjs

I have two server calls that I need to wait for. However, the user can decide if the second server call is even made. All of this is happening in an Angular Resolver, as the data is necessary for the next page.

The problem is that from my zip function the code never reaches the pipe, leaving me stuck in the resolver. Here is the procedure:

1. zip my requests
2. pipe them
3. and return an observable to my resolve function

this is my code:

```
public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):
    Observable<any> | Promise<any> { //

    const id = +route.paramMap.get('id');
    const wantsSecondRequest = +route.paramMap.get('wantsSecondRequest');


    const requests: Array<Observable<any>> = new Array();

    requests.push(firstServerCallHappensHere());
    if (wantsSecondRequest === 1) {
      requests.push(secondServerCallHappensHere());
    }

    return zip(requests).pipe(take(1), mergeMap(([a, b]) => {
         // DO STUFF WITH MY REQUESTS
          return of(a);
    }));
```

}

I tried it with Promise.all and working with Promises instead of Observables, but the issue with those are that I am unable to never complete the Promises in the case of an error, so that the navigation never happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the doc http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html `zip()` accepts a number of parameters which are observables but you provide an array. It might help:

```
public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):
    Observable<any> | Promise<any> { //

    const id = +route.paramMap.get('id');
    const wantsSecondRequest = +route.paramMap.get('wantsSecondRequest');

    return zip(
      firstServerCallHappensHere(),
      wantsSecondRequest === 1 ? secondServerCallHappensHere() : undefined,
    ).pipe(take(1), mergeMap(([a, b]) => {
         // DO STUFF WITH MY REQUESTS
          return of(a);
    }));
```

Comment: hey!
that worked indeed. However the Resolver resolves, even when an error occurs. This means I still reach the page behind the resolver and everything crashes there. This is how I subscribe to the return value of the Resolver: 
 `this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((data) => {// do stuff here });`
However, if something goes wrong and i call `return EMPTY`, i thought the resolver should not resolve and the navigation never occurs?

Comment: actually, i have to correct myself. In the resolver everything completes successfully, but nevertheless the handling in the subscribe function after the resolver completes does not work. Somehow the type of the return valued is not the right one. If i log the returned object from type Car it has all the properties, but  if(data.car instanceof Car) returns false. I guess this is my error right now.

Comment: Ok i found the issue! when subscribing, you have to take into consideration how you use the resolver in your route. e.g: `resolve: { myresolver: MyResolverService}`
Now you have to subscribe and access your data like this: `..subscribe((data: {myresolver:{whateverYouReturnedFromResolver}}) => ...`

Thanks @katzz0 for helping me with the zip function. !!